# Scraping Image from Instagram not working

Tags: python, image, web, instagram, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape images from Instagram using python. In order to do that, I have written a small piece of code. Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as req

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CE9CZmsghan/"

website = req(url)
pg = website.read()
website.close()

pgsoup = soup(pg,"html.parser")

print(pgsoup.findAll('div',{'class' : 'KL4Bh'}))
```

I have just written the code until converting the html into a soup object. Strangely, nothing is getting printing in the last line. Only an empty list is getting printed. Do you know why? And do you know how to fix it?

Comment: It is simply because javascript loads the image. you need selenium. this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) will help

Comment: Ok. What should I do with Selenium? Few lines of code would help me. Thx!

Comment: use the link in the comment. you'll find a few lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple with usage of `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os


chrome_driver = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CE9CZmsghan/'
browser.get(url)
image_url = browser.find_element_by_class_name('KL4Bh').find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
```

**Output**:

```
https://scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/119122193_326279868428134_4046851753042951785_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-frx5-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=MU53uPwIAzoAX-OPPES&_nc_tp=15&oh=7e874789a4624589c92c9c4f5e030387&oe=5F8F3371
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Should I download ChromeDriver for this?

Comment: @Sushil download from `https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads` based on you chrome version

Comment: Ok...But I couldn't find the 64-bit version of ChromeDriver for windows. Only 32 is available.

Comment: @Sushil then use 32 or change system to Linux

Comment: It is working now. Thanks! Is there any way to download all images from posts that have multiple images? Using the current code, I am only able to download one img. Pls help me.

Comment: @Sushil use `find_elements_` instead of `find_element` to collect list of elements

Comment: Okay Zaraki. If u feel that my question is good and is well-framed, then pls consider upvoting my question. Thank you!